# Counting a specific word in a dictionary

Tags: python, count

I'm trying to count the number of people 'online', given in the statuses dictionary. This is the code I have but it is outputting 0.

```py
def online_count(statuses):
    count = 0
    for x in statuses.items():
       if x =='online': 
          count += 1
    return count

statuses = {
    "Alice": "online",
    "Bob": "offline",
    "Eve": "online",
}

print(online_count(statuses))
```

Comment: Your `return count` should be after your `for` loop, not inside of it. Can also shorten the function to `return len([x for x in statuses.values() if x == 'online'])`

Comment: Did you mean: `for x in statuses.values():`?

Comment: Whenever I paste code in StackOverflow, it seems to mess up the formatting.  I've edited it to how it was- the return count was after the for loop.

Comment: Take a look at how I've formatted it. I find that using the delimiters is best. It completely eliminates the troublesome indentation problems.

Comment: @quamrana Yes! changing it to values worked! This is bizarre, given the site I did the challenge (pythonprinciples) hinted use of .items() - that's where I got it from! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```py
statuses = { "Alice": "online", "Bob": "offline", "Eve": "online", }

def online_count(statuses):
    lst = list(statuses.values())
    return lst.count("online")

print(online_count(statuses))
```

Basically, first it gets a list of all the values in the dictionary. In case you don't know, dictionaries are used to store data values in key:value pairs. Therefore, a list of all the values would mean a list of all the `"online"` / `"offlines"`

Answer (score 2):

Your return is indented too far. Move it outside the loop. That said you can use `sum` and a comprehension for this:

```
def online_count(statuses):
    return sum(s == 'online' for s in statuses.values())
```

Thanks @Sayandip Dutta!

Comment: Or `sum(s == 'online' for s in statuses.values())`

Comment: Ahh yes thank you that does look more readable I edited my answer